# How to highlight the clickable area of an image using map area="rect" - Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic4

I have a project in ionic4 in which I use the images of book and by using Map Area, I have defined coordinates to differentiate the sentences of the page. I need to highlight the sentence (rectangular area) when clicked.
Here is my code of home.html:

```
<div id="container" *ngIf="stretch" > 
<!-- <img *ngIf="showImage" src="{{showRoute}}" [ngClass]="{ 'img': color == null, 'img1': color == 
true }"> -->
<img *ngIf="showImage" src="{{showRoute}}" [width]="deviceWidth" [height]="deviceHeight"  
usemap="#metroid" ismap="ismap" border="0">
</div>
<map name="metroid" *ngFor="let map of localCoordinates; let i = index" >

<area shape="rect" coords="{{getCoordinates(i)}}" (pressup)="onPressUp($event, map)" 
(click)="coordinateClickFunc()">

</map>
```

Here is the code on home.ts

```
public getCoordinates(index) {
const localCoor = this.localCoordinates[index].coordinates;
let newx1 = localCoor.x1 * this.widthMultiplyFactor;
let newx2 = localCoor.x2 * this.widthMultiplyFactor;
let newy1 = localCoor.y1 * this.heightMultiplyFactor;
let newy2 = localCoor.y2 * this.heightMultiplyFactor;
let newCoor = newx1 + ',' + newy1 + ',' + newx2 + ',' + newy2;
// console.log('get coordinate function called', newCoor);
return newCoor;
}
```

Kindly help me the best way to change the background color of the clickable area of dynamic coordinates

Comment: Try this site https://www.image-map.net/ , you can select your image, set clickable areas. It returns you whole code.

Comment: I need to know how to change the backround